# Filtering results based on specific properties with specific values (cause timeout connection to DBpedia)

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

I'm trying to make a SPARQL query using Prolog and DBpedia. My objective is to tag in text all Persons, so for retrieving famous people I made this query that remove all results like Music groups(Band) and Organization, since I want to tag only real people and not abstract

```
 select ?person where{
  {
    ?person a dbpedia-owl:Person; rdfs:label "Name Surname" @it. 
  }
 UNION
  {
    ?person a dbpedia-owl:Person; foaf:name "Name"@it; foaf:surname "Surname"@it.      
  }
 UNION
  {
    ?person a dbpedia-owl:Person; foaf:name "Name Surname"@it.
  }

  FILTER NOT EXISTS  {
    {  ?subject <http://airpedia.org/ontology/type_with_conf#10> dbpedia-owl:Band .
       ?subject rdfs:label ?artistName .
       FILTER ( str(?artistName) = "Name Surname" ) 
    }
    UNION 
    { 
      ?subject <http://airpedia.org/ontology/type_with_conf#10>  dbpedia-owl:Organisation .
      ?subject rdfs:label ?artistName .
      FILTER ( str(?artistName) = "Name Surname" )
    }
  }
}
```

I use It. version of Dbpedia if you run this query use this version although the results will not be good for me.
So for example if I search "Metallica" as a person i don't want to get results cause is it a Band or(for me, but in this case is Metallica are an Organisation too) an Organisation 
 and it works good this are the results [Metallica Query Results](http://it.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=select+%3Fperson+where%7B%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%3Fperson+a+dbpedia-owl%3APerson%3B+rdfs%3Alabel+%22Metallica%22+%40it.+%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AUNION%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%3Fperson+a+dbpedia-owl%3APerson%3B+foaf%3Aname+%22Metallica%22%40it%3B+foaf%3Asurname+%22Metallica%22%40it.++++++%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AUNION%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%3Fperson+a+dbpedia-owl%3APerson%3B+foaf%3Aname+%22Metallica%22%40it.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AFILTER+NOT+EXISTS++%7B%0D%0A%7B+OPTIONAL%7B+%3Fsubject+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fairpedia.org%2Fontology%2Ftype_with_conf%2310%3E+dbpedia-owl%3ABand+.%0D%0A%3Fsubject+rdfs%3Alabel+%3FartistName+.%0D%0A+++%7D+FILTER+%28+str%28%3FartistName%29+%3D+%22Metallica%22+%29+%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A+UNION+%0D%0A%7B+OPTIONAL%7B%0D%0A+%3Fsubject+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fairpedia.org%2Fontology%2Ftype_with_conf%2310%3E++dbpedia-owl%3AOrganisation+.%0D%0A%3Fsubject+rdfs%3Alabel+%3FartistName+.%7D%0D%0AFILTER+%28+str%28%3FartistName%29+%3D+%22Metallica%22+%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&debug=on) and those are for "Michael Jackson" [Michael Jackson Query results](http://it.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=select+%3Fperson+where%7B%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%3Fperson+a+dbpedia-owl%3APerson%3B+rdfs%3Alabel+%22Michael+Jackson%22+%40it.+%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AUNION%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%3Fperson+a+dbpedia-owl%3APerson%3B+foaf%3Aname+%22Michael+Jackson%22%40it%3B+foaf%3Asurname+%22Michael+Jackson%22%40it.++++++%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AUNION%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%3Fperson+a+dbpedia-owl%3APerson%3B+foaf%3Aname+%22Michael+Jackson%22%40it.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AFILTER+NOT+EXISTS++%7B%0D%0A%7B+OPTIONAL%7B+%3Fsubject+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fairpedia.org%2Fontology%2Ftype_with_conf%2310%3E+dbpedia-owl%3ABand+.%0D%0A%3Fsubject+rdfs%3Alabel+%3FartistName+.%0D%0A+++%7D+FILTER+%28+str%28%3FartistName%29+%3D+%22Michael+Jackson%22+%29+%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A+UNION+%0D%0A%7B+OPTIONAL%7B%0D%0A+%3Fsubject+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fairpedia.org%2Fontology%2Ftype_with_conf%2310%3E++dbpedia-owl%3AOrganisation+.%0D%0A%3Fsubject+rdfs%3Alabel+%3FartistName+.%7D%0D%0AFILTER+%28+str%28%3FartistName%29+%3D+%22Michael+Jackson%22+%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&debug=on)

My problem is when i put someone that is not a Singer or a Music band for example if i try something like "Jim Carrey" i get " error transction timed out Jim Carrey.

I think I got this problem because those properties are Undefined for Jim Carrey, but i tried an to put an OPTIONAL marker in each subquery in the first filter, but i get too the same error
I put the code in a pastebin file so you can find all three query

I know that i should not use Static String in a query or there are a lot of better mode but i need that since i compose the query with prolog and than send to sparql online so i must do in this way.

TO @Joshua I tried to remove the FILTER(String) in the NOT EXIST (Filter) But I will not work anymore thanks however for helping me

Excuse me for too much editing but i resolved some part of the starting problem but didn't find a solution
First problem :Filtering results based on specific properties with specific values. (Works)
Second : The first works only for Things with that specific property (as show above) like(Metallica,Michael Jackson, The Beatles, ...) but not for thos without the properties in the filter.

(i can't use more than two link because I'm a newbe so i will put a link in the comments with a pastebin links with the 3 Query and the results of they)

Comment: Since there's probably no one or thing with the name `"Name Surname"@it` in DBpedia, it's some what difficult to reproduce your results.  Is there any chance you could use a real name here that for which you get the problematic results?  Then we can test whether the solutions are actually working.

Comment: In this pastebin file you can find my 3 query (always the same query with different Values and link to the result to Jim Carrey Query beacuse i can't link that :
http://pastebin.com/C14jAtRM